# Base page and sub pages

Tags: php, html

There's a website I'm trying to recreate as they have a distributor in a new country and I'm trying to get their website done (This is stated in case anyone thinks I'm plagiarizing their content).

The website I'm trying to copy is https://www.powerair.eu

On their products page they have a submenu that allows one to navigate pages but from what I can tell, the submenus are linked to pages like https://www.powerair.eu/products.php?sl=en&parent=car

I use a fairly standard form of html where I would create a separate page for each product and the whole "&parent=car" part is confusing because when I check the source code for it, it looks like the same "products.php" page but the content is different.

Can someone please explain to me how this part works (where it displays different content but still has the same base page) I need to get this done quickly so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is too early to make a comment without seeing the code. From the description, I assume that `products.php` is a page that will be filtering the products based on the `$_GET['parent']`. Check it.

Comment: @Ash1271 From what I just searched on the pages, there's no $_GET variable on the page and neither is it coded in php. The page just has the php extension. It doesn't use <?php> anywhere.

Comment: Could you please paste the code products.php in your question?

Comment: You can't read the PHP file if you 'view source' in your browser. The PHP file is on the server. If you are only seeing HTML this tells me that you don't have access to their source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It uses the `$_GET` global variable.
It may be using some underlying logic that relies on the value of that variable. For an instance if a page url looks like

```
https://example.com/sample.php?product=shoes
```

A developer may use the `$_GET['product']` variable to access its value.

For an example it can be:

```
<body>
  <?php
     $dynamic_value = isset($_GET['product']) ? $_GET['product'] : 'Default Value';
  ?>

  <h1><?php echo $dynamic_value ?></h1>

</body>
```

By utilizing the logic above, one can use the `$_GET["product"]` variable to fetch data on database etc.

however there are safety precautions that must be tackled such as sanitizing inputs and more. You can read more about using the `$_GET` variable [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Comment: From what I just searched on the pages, there's no $_GET variable on the page and neither is it coded in php. The page just has the php extension. It doesn't use <?php> anywhere.

Comment: url parameters such as `?foo=bar` can also be accessed by various programming languages. It can also be access by using `javascript` for an example. Do you have a copy of the actual file/page? using the browser's `view-source` won't actually show you any server side logic such as `php` unless it is designed to be accessible at the client side

Comment: No I do not have the complete source because it was built by someone else within the czech republic. I just need to reproduce the pages and remove a lot of products that the company I'm doing it for doesn't supply.

Comment: If so then you can't safely say "It doesn't use <?php> anywhere" for server side logic aren't supposed to be seen/visible at the client side. My guess is that it actually utilizes the `$_GET` variable like the answer I've posted

Comment: @Chamkey From your comments, I guess you're referring to the page source of that `.php` code. As @jpneey said, what you're seeing in the browser is server render code having HTML and javascript only. There you won't find any PHP source code. However, if you have no access to the code, you should write your own logic.

Comment: Just a hint to proceed further, 
In your products.php page, read the value of `$_GET['parent']` and pass it to the code which is fetching the products from the database. Then in your code to read products from db, use the value of $_GET['parent'] to filter the products. 
E.g. If you are using MySQL and PHP, your DB query should be something like, 

`"SELECT * FROM products WHERE filed_name = '$parent'";`
Where products is the database table and field_name is the column in `products` table having `parent` value.